# Use relative url with webpack - not <base href="/">

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I've found a lot of examples of web applications built/packaged with **webpack**. All use `<base href="/">` or the like.

My preferred way for a web application is using no base, but locate all resources relative to index.html. This is especially important when developing PhoneGap-like web applications running in a WebView.

And of course I don't want to run the build-script only because someone decided to move the application to another place.

Is there a solid solution to avoid `<base href="/">`?

Comment: How *a lot of examples* forces you to use `<base href="/">` in your own code?

Comment: OK, a lot of is 2-3 (all examples / seed projects I've seen). I'll try to remove the line completely, because `<!--<base href="/">-->` didn't work but might be detected as if it was meant to be `<base href="/">`.